# stuck a point on advantages of virtual memory management

Tags: unix, process, linux-kernel, cpu

> Most modern operating systems, employ virtual memory management, a
> technique that confers two main advantages:
>
> ✗ Processes are isolated from one another and from the kernel, so that
> one process can’t read or modify the memory of another process or the
> kernel.
>
> ✗ Only part of a process needs to be kept in memory, thereby lowering
> the memory requirements of each process and allowing more processes to
> be held in RAM simultaneously. This leads to better CPU utilization,
> since it increases the likelihood that, at any moment in time, there
> is at least one process that the CPU(s) can execute.
>
> Source: The Linux Programming Interface: A Linux and UNIX System Programming Handbook, Michael Kerrisk

I don't understand the part of second explanation that this leads to better CPU utilization,
since it increases the likelihood that, at any moment in time, *there
is **at least** one process that the CPU(s) can execute.* Can you clarify the sentence ? Is there a rule that there must be at least one process to be ready to be executed by CPU(s) or something similar? Why is it needed?

Comment: With more memory, more processes remain memory resident and within closer reach of a CPU looking for something to do. I see your point, does it mean virtual-memory management (as opposed to virtual memory-management and why would one assume virtual memory can be anything but managed?)? If so they are not really memory resident but paged out to disk, still, they are more quickly recoverable by an idle CPU.

Comment: The key is that virtual memory permits a process to be *partially* resident, vs the all-or-nothing case more likely to be forced without.  There's of course no rule that says that a processor always must have something useful to do; but not having anything able to be executed when there is desired work outstanding is pretty obviously a CPU utilization hit.

Comment: It is not strictly "needed", unless you want to improve the utilisation of your hardware as close to 100% as possible, something which is usually an unspoken requirement.

Answer (score -1):

Well, this whole definition is completely incorrect.

> Processes are isolated from one another and from the kernel, so that
>   one process can’t read or modify the memory of another process or the
>   kernel.

This implies that processes have no way of communicating with each other and with the kernel. The isolation provided by virtual memory only means that an unauthorized process cannot directly (in contrast to indirectly through system calls) access the memory allocated for another process.

> Only part of a process needs to be kept in memory, thereby lowering
>   the memory requirements of each process and allowing more processes to
>   be held in RAM simultaneously.

Memory requirements of each process are not lowered, they remain the same. Instead, virtual memory creates the illusion that there is more physical main memory than what is actually installed on the system.

> This leads to better CPU utilization, since it increases the
>   likelihood that, at any moment in time, there is at least one process
>   that the CPU(s) can execute.

This does not necessarily increase CPU utilization or the likelihood of always having schedulable processes compared to no virtual memory. It depends on what each process is doing, how much memory each process requires, how processes interact with each other, and how the OS allocates and manages memory.

The illusion of larger physical memory has the following benefits:

- Makes the system more interactive by running multiple processes irrespective of their memory demand. This does not necessarily mean the whole system or any individual process is running faster (or slower) in any sense of the word.
- Enhances the portability of applications since they can transparently run on systems with different amounts of physical memory.

There are other benefits of virtual memory. I suggest reading OS books and other resources.